# How to Pass a variable in Image source in HTML JSP page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have written a JSP login Page in which I am getting USER name and based on the user name I need to show the picture of the user from images folder,for doing it I have changed the name of the images based on userid ,so whenever the user will enter username based on username it will get userpic .below is the code in which I am fetching username and trying to apply it in image source.

```
<SCRIPT>
var request_custom;  
    function userId()  
        {  
           var userId = (document.getElementById("<%=userFieldName%>").value);
    alert("SamDONE"+userId);
        }      
</SCRIPT>



<div style="background: **url(images/<%=userFieldName%>.jpg)**;width:200px; height:180px; font-size:40 ";>
```

Please let me know how can I pass the variable in order to get the image.

Comment: That looks right. What happens when you run the code? What does the generated HTML/CSS/JS look like? (Use View > Source in your browser).

Answer (score -1):

If you want data from the model to be available in javascript you will need to store it somewhere on the rendered page.

You can use your JSP to write JavaScript assigning your model to JavaScript variables.

```
<script>
    var userId =<c:out value="${userFieldName}"/>
</script>
```

Another solution could use one hidden input, and then read the hidden input value from javascript

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenUserName" value='${userFieldName}'/>

<script>
    var userId = document.getElementById("hiddenUserName");
</script>
```

You can then set style of an element from javascript

```
<div id="imgDiv"></div>

<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("imgDiv");
    elem.style.background = 'url(images/' + userId + '.png)'; //assuming image is a .png file
    elem.style.width='200px';
    elem.style.height='180px';
    elem.style.fontSize = "40px";
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't help get the username to the browser from the server in the first place.